# Robospice Offline Service Implemintation

Tags: android, offline, retrofit, robospice

I want to use Robospice for Networking and long tasks.
Currently, I implemented two SpiceServices
1. ServerSpiceService - RetrofitSpiceService
2. OfflineSpiceService - As seen in [Robospice Offline Sample](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/tree/release/robospice-sample-core-offline)

Although it seems to work, when testing it in offline mode (Device in Flight Mode), i get Request error due to "Network is off" when using the offline spice manager. Needless to say, I implemented NetworkStateChecker as in the sample code.
While debugging, i've noticed that the getNetworkStateChecker() is never called, moreover the offline service never gets bound or started.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Did you override method getNetworkStateChecker() in your OfflineService like in sample: https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/blob/release/robospice-sample-core-offline/src/com/octo/android/robospice/sample/offline/SampleOfflineSpiceService.java ? If you did - problems may be in code.

Comment: yes i copied exactly the same code. I created the manager the following way. The funny thing is it actually works but the debug prints doesn't support it. 
I think i'll strip the code down to a minimal and try figuring it out.

Comment: What about stacktrace of exception? Can you print it here please?

Comment: Solved !!! 
Forgot to add the Offline Service to the Manifest ... oopsy